# Location Services: 'Blue Bar' during 'Always' Mode

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, privacy

As far as I looked/searched and implemented so far. The blue far should not appear when user has granted 'Always' use location services. But one of my client is getting blue bar on his iOS 12 phone. It also happened to him with google maps application, but i could not replicate it on my device.

Blue bar message says: "Google maps is actively using your location"

Is it possible, is there any other reason that is causing blue bar to appear?

---

**POP UP ALERT:**

Based on given answer's by Mr Tawk and Roee, it leads me to wonder the if the blue bar will be shown by setting `showsBackgroundLocationIndicator` to `true`, then will the popup alert will also be shown to the user? Saying: "ABC app is accessing your location in the background." Like below, as mentioned here : [About privacy and Location Services in iOS 8 and later](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033)

[image: background location use alert]

Comment: 'Blue Bar' appears when I using Google Maps turn by turn navigation and the app is in the background. I thought turning 'Blue Bar' off is not allowed by iOS.

Comment: If Always permission is granted, it is hidden. But it has random behaviour.

Comment: if you still have any further questions I would gladly help you out! @Bista

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make sure that the user really gave the app 'Always authorization', and that you **didn't** set the flag showsBackgroundLocationIndicator.

See Apple documentation regarding this:

> Starting with iOS 11, apps have more control over the appearance of the Location Services Status Bar (Blue Bar) for their apps.
>
> Apps which are given When-in-use authorization by the users
>   (regardless of the authorization asked for), will automatically get
>   the Blue Bar displayed. Apps cannot opt out of the Blue Bar if they
>   are only given When-in-use authorization by the users.
>
> Apps which are given Always authorization, on the other hand, will get
>   the Blue Bar displayed based on a new property of the
>   CLLocationManager object.
>
> @property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsBackgroundLocationIndicator;
>
> Apps which have their Continuous Background Location session active,
>   and have obtained Always authorization the Blue Bar will be shown only
>   when the showsBackgroundLocationIndicator property is YES.
>
> An app can toggle the showsBackgroundLocationIndicator property to
>   change the visibility of the blue bar at any time.

At those links:

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1965/_index.html
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/2923541-showsbackgroundlocationindicator

**EDIT**:
 Regarding the new question - POP UP ALERT:

Your app should ask the user permission to use the location services
[image: request permission]

For always/while using the app.
If the user agreed to always allow, the iOS might remind him that the app is able to use his location.

see this part

> Other apps will ask for access to your location even when the app isn't in use. When you allow an app to always use your location, iOS will remind you which apps are able to use your location after an app uses your location in the background.

at https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT203033

This usually happens once, see Apple's answer to a question at their forums:

> A few days after the app obtains the "always" authorization and starts
>   using location services in the background, the user will be asked to
>   confirm once again that they still want this app to track their
>   location in the background.
>
> There is no developer action that can be taken to avoid this
>   confirmation if the app is obtaining users' location in the
>   background.

And this thread [Removing the background location alerts in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514717/removing-the-background-location-alerts-in-ios)

Comment: Seems legit. I have appended my concern in the post though.

Comment: If you check the image i have attached a popup is shown. It is shown at random time after user has given the 'Always' to the app. This popup is shown by OS itself. So if the blue bar feature is enabled is case of 'Always' also, will this popup be shown then too? Because this popup is shown for 'Always' case only, not for 'while in use'. It is tested and for sure that popup is shown for always case, but not sure about whether it will be shown for 'show bar' case.

Comment: The popup will be shown for 'Always' (and won't be shown for 'while').
The blue bar should appear only if the user choose 'while' or if u set the flag showsBackgroundLocationIndicator. For that reason I would ask the user to check again and make sure he choose the 'Always' permission.

Comment: So for Always mode, it doesn't matter whether 'showsBackgroundLocationIndicator' is set to 'true/false', the OS will remind user with the popup attached above in my post? Keeping in mind that, blue bar is visible to the user if it is set to true?

Comment: Correct. This popup comes from the OS for apps with 'Always', and you can't control it.

Answer (score 2):

Apple in iOS 11 has removed the Blue banner that displays for apps that used the location of the iPhone. Displaying the Blue bar for background location use is left to the app developer through a property.

```
open var showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: Bool
```

**From Apple:**

This property affects only apps that received always authorization. When such an app moves to the background, the system uses this property to determine whether to change the status bar appearance to indicate that location services are in use. Displaying a modified status bar gives the user a quick way to return to your app. The default value of this property is NO.

For apps with when-in-use authorization, the system always changes the status bar appearance when the app uses location services in the background.

Comment: Seems legit. I have appended my concern in the post though.

Comment: If you check the image i have attached a popup is shown. It is shown at random time after user has given the 'Always' to the app. This popup is shown by OS itself. So if the blue bar feature is enabled is case of 'Always' also, will this popup be shown then too? Because this popup is shown for 'Always' case only, not for 'while in use'. It is tested and for sure that popup is shown for always case, but not sure about whether it will be shown for 'show bar' case.

Comment: well I tried to reproduce your issue but It's normal with me maybe sharing your location class would help @Bista

Comment: It is not related to my class, it is just a general query. That is, for Always mode, if 'showsBackgroundLocationIndicator' is set to 'true/false', the OS will remind user with the popup, attached above in my post, or not, since blue bar is visible to the user if it is set to true?

Comment: True 'showsBackgroundLocationIndicator' is the indicator to allow this or deny it